# How do I show there exists $N$ such that $n \ge N \implies n^2 < 2^n$?

Tags: real-analysis

> How do I show there exists $N$ such that $n \ge N \implies n^2 < 2^n$?

I know, from experience really, that if $N=5$, then $n \ge N \implies n^2<2^n$. But how do I find this $N$ directly?

Comment: My favorite proof is to note that $(1+1)^n>n+\binom n2+\binom n {n-2}$ for $n\ge5$.

Answer (score 0):

By taking log on $n^2 < 2^n$, we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{\log n}{n} < \frac{\log 2}{2}
\end{equation}
Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} \log n /n = 0$, there exists $N$ such that 
for all $n \ge N$,
$$ \log n / n < \log 2 / 2$$
which proves the problem.

[Edited] Since you ask what is $N$?, here it is.
Let $f(x) = \log x / x$ and 
$$ f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}(1-\log x)$$
Thus $f$ has maximum at $x = e$ and for $x > e$, $f' < 0$, i.e. $f$ is decreasing.
Therefore, since for $x = 5$, $f(5) < \log 2 / 2$, we conclude that 
$$ f(x) \le f(5) < \log2 / 2, \qquad \text{for all $x \ge$ 5} $$
Thus $N = 5$.

Comment: Ok, now what is this new $N$?

Comment: @AlJebr See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should start with $N=5$ ($n\geq 5$) and then try to use mathematical induction to argue about the validity of the inequality.